# number of ways to make a selection

Tags: permutations

In a book I saw a paragraph , but I cannot understand what is the logic behind that  [image]

Can anybody explain me this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start with a slightly different question: How many ways are there to take *none or more* items?  If there is only one kind of item, and p of that item, obviously you can take 0, 1, 2, ..., p of them, so there are (p+1) ways of taking none or more.  If there are two kinds of items, p of the first and q of the second, then whatever you take will have none-or-more of the first and none-or-more of the second, so you can reinterpret this as taking none-or-more of the first, THEN none-or-more of the second, independently of each other, and that independence implies a product, (p+1)(q+1).  The generalization to more kinds is obvious.  Now your original question is exactly the same *except* that you are not allowed to NOT take any items, so you have to subtract 1 to NOT count the case where you take none of any of them.

Answer (score 1):

The 1 in the formula comes from the choice of 0 things of the respective kind.